# Add dash/hyphen after 4 digits in edittext in android

Tags: android

I was implemented like after 4 digits hyphen display automatically like(2015-07) in edittext. my code works fine, but problem is while i delete before 4 digits value and again type it not working. addTextChangedListener not trigger when i edidtext retype like 2015-07 to 2014-07. But while i using "/" instead of "-" i can retype value. What is the problem?

```
mEdtProductionCode.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        int prevL = 0;
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            prevL = mEdtProductionCode.getText().toString().length();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            int length = s.length();
            if ((prevL < length) && length == 4) {
                String data = mEdtProductionCode.getText().toString();
                mEdtProductionCode.setText(data + "-");
                mEdtProductionCode.setSelection(length + 1);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: No one answer??

Comment: Problem is with `prevL` vs `length` comparison.

If you delete a character before digit no 4, your `prevL` will be > than `length` and no code in `afterTextChanged` method get executed

Answer (score 0):

You should just move your character checking to the character after the fifth character has been entered, and then chop down String to put the custom character in between:

```
 @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            int length = s.length();
            if ((prevL <= length) && length == 5) {

                String data = mEditProductionCode.getText().toString();
                String beginData = data.substring(0,4);

                String endData = Character.toString(data.charAt(length-1));
                mEditProductionCode.setText(beginData + "-" + endData);
                mEditProductionCode.setSelection(length + 1);
            }
        }
```

You can also use `data.charAt(length-1) != '-'` to check if user manually made dash input, in which case you just ignore and do not make changes to TextEdit.